# when I use python for scripting Login response code showing like 400 but in application shows 302 response. how to resolve it in locust

Tags: python, locust

In my script when I login it shows like 400 response code.

```
from locust import task, SequentialTaskSet, HttpUser, between
import re

class Orange(SequentialTaskSet):
def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.csrf1 = ""
    self.csrf2 = ""

@task
def launch(self):
    with self.client.get("/", name="T01_Launch", catch_response=True) as response:
        if "OrangeHRM" in response.text:
            response.success()
        else:
            response.failure("Failed to launch")
        try:
            csrf1 = re.search(r"_csrf_token\" value=(.+?)\"", response.text)
            self.csrf1 = csrf1.group(1)
        except AttributeError:
            self.csrf1 = "NOT FOUND_CSRF 1"
@task
def login(self):
    self.client.cookies.clear()
    data = {
        "actionID": "",
        "hdnUserTimeZoneOffset": 5.5,
        "installation": "",
        "_csrf_token": self.csrf1,
        "txtUsername": "Admin",
        "txtPassword": "admin123",
        "Submit": "LOGIN"
    }

        with self.client.post("/index.php/auth/validateCredentials", name="T02_Login",catch_response=True) as response:
        print(response.status_code)   #THIS LINE SHOWING 400 RESPONSE CODE


class Myuser(HttpUser):
host = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com"
wait_time = between(1, 2)
tasks = [Orange]    #USER CLASS
```

When I was checked the application login transanction redirected so it shows 302 code.
Orange HRM application shows like 302 response code for Login. if anyone helps me it would be great...

Answer (score 0):

A [302 is a redirect response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), telling the client to go somewhere else to complete the request. It's possible the server logs you're looking at are logging the 302 and redirecting the client somewhere else which means you may need to look at another log on another server somewhere to find the rest of the request.

Locust's client inherits from Requests, which means you should be able to try things like [`get_redirect_target`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.get_redirect_target) or check the Response object for [`history`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.history) to see where the request may have been redirected to which may help you in your search for where to look server side for the request handling.

It may also be helpful to take Locust out of the equation and create a standalone Python script that does what you need it to do. Use Requests for your client calls and it should be pretty easy to move everything back over to Locust when you get it working.

Comment: Hi solowalker
If you give clear picture about that issue, it helps me great? Can you tell clearly....